# Illustrated book with a teenage vampire, werewolf & two Frankenstein's monsters at school

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to figure out the title of this book (maybe series of books?) that I read when I was a child.

I read it sometime during the mid 90s if I recall correctly.  The story involved some young monsters attending a (normal human) school, and the main human character befriending them.  There was the vampire kid who drank blood from a thermos with a straw, the wolfkid who got around everywhere on a skateboard, and the two Frankenstein's monsters siblings.

Another major plot point was, if I'm remembering correctly, that there was a school project or something, and the group built a model of their school.  However, it was ruined by the school bully(?) and they had to figure out who did it.

I also remember a scene where they were at the Frankenstein's monsters kids house, and they ordered pizza, but the vampire kid and the wolfkid freaked out over it and fled.

It was also illustrated, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [Fifth Grade Monsters](http://www.melgilden.com/Essays/Musings/MusingEssays/Essay06.html) series by Mel Gilden.

> In the first volume, M Is for Monster (1987), Danny Keegan, a "normal"
>   fifth grader, was introduced to the new kids in class. They include C. D.
>   Bitesky (a vampire), Howie Wolfner (a werewolf), and Elisa and Frankie
>   Stein (who bore more than a passing resemblance to Frankenstein and his
>   bride). Gilden took Danny and the "monsters" through a series of
>   adventures, most with plots that focused on the importance of young
>   people's acceptance of kids who are slightly different.